# How to build a server that accepts many thousands of persistent network connections?

Tags: linux, performance, networking, network-programming

I am about build a server on linux (I get to pick programming language) that accepts many TCP/IP socket persistent connections from a desktop software. How can this be done cheaply and efficiently? A machine cannot have more than 60000 ports, so if I have to support 600k connections then I will need 10 linux boxes?

Since the computation needed for each connection is extremely small (idle 95% of the time) one linux box can already handle 600k I don't want to waste money and resource running 10 boxes just to get around port limitations.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are running a server, you only need one port to bind to - not one port for each client.

Comment: Doesn't it create a server port upon accepting the connection?

Comment: It creates server socket, which is pair of client(ip:port)-server(ip:port)

Comment: Since you're about to write a Unix network server daemon: lighttpd is one of these, and you should look at the source. The `main()` function in src/server.c is a terse list of all the standard things a network daemon is expected to do: write a pid file, respond to SIGHUP, double-fork to get away from a controlling tty, etc. http://www.lighttpd.net/

Comment: If you are serving 600k clients, 10 boxes is NOT a waste of money, as you will probably want more than that anyway (in practice). Talk to your operations team, who should probably know something about capacity management if they are planning to operate this application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A connection is identified by the following tuple: [Server IP;Server Port; Client IP; Client Port], hence, more than 60,000 ports are available per machine.

Erlang effectively handles 10's of 1000s of connections. Have a look at this [comparison](http://www.sics.se/~joe/apachevsyaws.html) between Apache and Erlang Yaws.

Comment: So according to that tuple, there isn't really a limit on the server side outside of memory limitations? I got it wrong then.

Comment: @erotsppa: that's what I like about SO: you can always learn new things!  Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You do **NOT** need a port for each connection. An HTTP server will just use one port (typically 80).

Comment: Port 80 is a *great* example of this; +1.

Answer (score 1):

Since any relatively widely used language has a reasonably efficient socket library I would go for a language that:

1. Is efficient in whatever the processing you need to do with the data from the desktops
2. You are familiar enough (read; most familiar) with to avoid the most common pitfalls / design patterns

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this easily with any framework which is decent. We use Twisted which is good (Assuming you understand python and asynchronous programming), if a little weird to understand.

Asynchronous programming is pretty much a given, because you will probably NOT want to start 600k threads.